# Chord of a conic touches another conic

Tags: conic-sections, polar-coordinates, tangent-line

If $P, Q, R$ are three points on the conic $\frac{l}{r}=1+e\cos\theta$ and the tangent at $Q$ meets $SP$ and $SR$ in $M$ and $N$ so that $SM=SN=l$, where $S$ is the focus, then prove that the chord $PR$ touches the conic

$\frac{l}{r}=1+2e\cos\theta$

**MY ATTEMPT:**

Let $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ be vectorial angle of the points $P, Q, R$ respectively.

Equation of tangent at $Q$ is
$\frac{l}{r} = e\cos\theta+\cos(\theta-\beta)$

Equation of chord $PR$ is
$\frac{l}{r} = \sec{(\frac{\gamma-\alpha}{2})}\cos{(\theta-\frac{\gamma+\alpha}{2})} + e\cos\theta$

Coordinates of $M$ and $N$ are $(l, \alpha)$ and $(l, \gamma)$ respectively.

I don't know how to reduce the equation of chord $PQ$ to a equation which is identical with the equation of a tangent

Comment: Playing in geogebra I can make sense of the equation of tangent at $Q$ and of chord $PR$, but fixing $P$ and $Q$ such that $SM=SN=l$ I don't necessarily get the angles of $P$ and $R$ as the angles of $M$ and $N$. maybe I'm getting it wrong, because I don't get $PR$ to be tangent to $\frac{l}{r}=1+2e\cos\theta$ either. Could you provide a figure?

Comment: This question was asked in our university exam and this question is also in our book. I too do not understand how to solve this question.